# How to find charpoly from eigenvalues and CH to prove an equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

For an uknown 3x3 matrix $A$ we know that $\operatorname{tr} A = 0$, $\det(A) = 1/4$ and we also know that two eigenvalues are the same. Proove that $4A^3 = -3A - I$. Problem says to use Vieta to find characteristic polynomial and Cayley-Hamilton after.

I get that $2L_1 + L_3 = 0$ and $L_1^2 = 1/4$ but i do know how to proceed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @ mkontakis:  there are some questions with your question.  Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some concerns about the statement of this question:  first, the desired result should read

$4A^3 = 3A + I, \tag{X1}$

not

$4A^3 = -3A - I; \tag{X2}$

and second, we must assume the eigenvalues of $A$ are all real.  This follows, as will be seen below, if $A$ is real.  We can also assume, for example that $A$ is complex Hermtitian, $A^\dagger = A$, or it can be hypothesized directly.  An example of non-real, non-Hermitian $A$ satisfying $\text{Tr}(A) = 0$ and $\det(A) = \frac{1}{4}$ will be provided below.

These things being noted, here's how I proceed:

For *any* real or complex $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$, the characteristic polynomial $p_A(x)$ factors into linear factors, thus:

$p_A(x) = (x - \lambda_1)(x - \lambda_2)(x - \lambda_3), \tag{1}$

where the $\lambda_i$, $1 \le i \le 3$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.  When the factors on the right-hand side of (1) are multiplied out, the well known result

$p_A(x) = (x - \lambda_1)(x - \lambda_2)(x - \lambda_3)$
$= x^3 - (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3)x^2 + (\lambda_1 \lambda_2 + \lambda_1  \lambda_3 + \lambda_2 \lambda_3)x - (\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3) \tag{2}$

is readily obtained.  Since

$\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = \text{Tr}(A) = 0\tag{3}$

and

$\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3 = \det(A) = \dfrac{1}{4}, \tag{4}$

we see that (2) may be written as

$p_A(x) = x^3 + (\lambda_1 \lambda_2 + \lambda_1  \lambda_3 + \lambda_2 \lambda_3)x -\dfrac{1}{4}. \tag{5}$

We also know that two eigenvalues are equal, so let us assume that $\lambda_2 = \lambda_3$.
Then from (3) we have

$\lambda_1 + 2\lambda_2 = 0 \tag{6}$

and thus

$\lambda_3 = \lambda_2 = -\dfrac{1}{2} \lambda_1. \tag{7}$

Now (4) and (7) together imply

$\dfrac{\lambda_1^3}{4} = \dfrac{1}{4}, \tag{8}$

and also, from (7) alone,

$\lambda_2 \lambda_3 = \dfrac{1}{4}\lambda_1^2 \tag{9}$

and

$\lambda_1 \lambda_2 = \lambda_1 \lambda_3 = -\dfrac{1}{2}\lambda_1^2, \tag{10}$

so that

$\lambda_1 \lambda_2 + \lambda_1  \lambda_3 + \lambda_2 \lambda_3 = -\dfrac{3}{4}\lambda_1^2; \tag{11}$

the characteristic polynomial $p_A(x)$ thus becomes

$p_A(x) = x^3 - \dfrac{3}{4}\lambda_1^2 x - \dfrac{1}{4}. \tag{12}$

(12) is as far as we can go without the above-mentioned further assumptions on $A$.  To illustrate this by means of an example, consider the diagonal, complex matrix

$A = \begin{bmatrix}  e^{2\pi i / 3} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -\dfrac{1}{2} e^{2\pi i / 3} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -\dfrac{1}{2} e^{2\pi i / 3} \end{bmatrix}. \tag{13}$

It is easily seen that $\text{Tr}(A) = 0$ and $\det(A) = \frac{1}{4}$; but by the Hamilton-Cayley theorem (12) yields

$0 = p_A(A) = A^3 - \dfrac{3}{4}e^{4 \pi i / 3} A - \dfrac{1}{4} I \Rightarrow 4A^3 - 3e^{4 \pi i / 3} A -I = 0; \tag{14}$

we certainly have neither (X1) nor (X2) in this event; indeed, if say (X1) were true then

$3A + I = 4A^3 = 3e^{4 \pi i / 3} A + I \tag{15}$

or

$e^{4 \pi i / 3} A = A, \tag{16}$

which can only hold if $A = 0$; certainly, $\det(A) \ne \frac{1}{4}$ in *that* case!  And if (X2) held then

$-3A - I = 3e^{4 \pi i / 3} A + I \tag{17}$

or

$-3(1 + e^{4 \pi i / 3})A = 2I, \tag{18}$

and it is easy to see (18) rules out $\text{Tr}(A) = 0$.

If all the eigenvalues of $A$ are real, then (8) or its equivalent

$\lambda_1^3 = 1, \tag{19}$

shows that $\lambda_1 = 1$; then (12) becomes

$p_A(x) = x^3 - \dfrac{3}{4} x - \dfrac{1}{4}, \tag{20}$

and so by Hamilton-Cayley we have

$4A^3 = 3A + I, \tag{21}$

that is, (X1).  The condition that two eigenvalues are the same if sufficient to force all eigenvalues of a *real* $3 \times 3$ $A$ matrix to be real as well:  since the characteristic polynomial must have degree $3$, an odd number, in this case $A$ has at least one real eigenvalue, say $\mu$.  If some other eigenvalue $\nu = \mu$, then $p_A(x)$ is divisible by $(x - \mu)^2$ over the real field $\Bbb R$.  Then the quotient must be a real linear factor $x - \sigma$, showing $A$ has all real eigenvalues.  The only other possibility is that no other eigenvalue $\nu = \mu$, but then we would have to have $\nu = \bar \nu$, so $\nu$ is forced to be real as well.  In such a situation (X1)-(21) holds.

(X2) is false under the stated hypothesis, since (X1)-(21) would then force $6A + 2I = 0$, contradicting the condition on $\text{Tr}(A)$.  A careful inspection of Git Gud's answer shows that it implies (X1), *not* (X2), as well.

And I'm done.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Thank you for the extended analysis. !! The statement of the quesation is clear.. It is 4A^3 = -3A - I

Comment: @ mkontakis:  I can see no flaw in my analysis, so perhaps in light of it I should suggest that there is a typo and/or misprint in the book/problem sheet from which you received the question?  That's a fairly common occurrance . . .